# combination of rewrite rules not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.com$  //redirect from .net and .org to .com
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] //Always use www.
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?article-(.*)$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC] // redirect article-x  to article.php?id=x
RewriteRule ^/?page-(.*)$ page?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]// redirect page-x  to page.php?p=x
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L] // add the .php to every request if the file type is missing
```

all the rules work fine except for adding www. to url. for example http://domain.com/page-1
doesn't get redirected to http://www.domain.com/page-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%1` refers to a pattern captured with `()` in the preceding `RewriteCond`. You haven't captured any patterns in `RewriteCond`. Instead, you can just use `%{HTTP_HOST}` in the `RewriteRule`.

If these rules reside in .htaccess, `RewriteRule` will not contain a leading `/`, and will therefore never match if your pattern does.  Remove the `/` and match on `^(.*)$`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

Side note: don't forget to escape the `.` in `.com`. It will work unescaped,  but the expression doesn't mean what you literally intend it to mean.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$
```

The full set of rewrites all together should look like the following (I have removed all the leading `/` and `/?` expressions). I have tested all of this as working on my own system.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [NC]
#Use a capture group here, add [L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^article-(.*)$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^page-(.*)$ page?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: the .net to .com redirect works fine but i can still visit the website without www.

Comment: Is this in .htaccess or in a `VirtualHost` config?

Comment: .htaccess in my hosting

Comment: Then the issue is probably the leading `/` in `RewriteRule`. See edit I made above.

Comment: u r right. it works after removing the leading /. if I try to go to 
http://example.net/page-a
it redirects to:
http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/page-a

all other normal redirections seem to work fine

Comment: @nullException I did some testing and seem to have worked it out.

Comment: @nullException Good, I'm glad I could help.